# Don't order by id record in collection attribute with Sails.js

Tags: javascript, model, sails.js, waterline

I'm working on Sails.js I'm trying to store some tracks in my playlist model.

It's like that :

```
Playlist = {
 attributes : {
  tracks: {
   collection: 'track'
  }
 }
}
```

My problem is that a playlist have a tracklist where the tracks have a specific order.

For example when I create a playlist :

```
var tracksIds = [5,2,10];
// Create
Playlist.create({tracks: tracksIds})
 // Return => 
    Playlist = {
     tracks: [2,5,10]
    }

// Needed => 
   Playlist = {
    tracks: [5,2,10]
   }
```

So my question is : how to force Sails to not order by Id the records in tracks collection ?

Thank's !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep order information, you'll need an order attribute somewhere.

In pure relational database logic, you'd want an intermediate table between Playlist and Track. First, because the many<->many relationship requires it, and Second, to store order information for tracks in a Playlist.

How to implement this in Sails? Well the documentation specifies that this isn't possible yet:
http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/associations/through-associations

They suggest that you create the intermediate model yourself as a workaround.

That means you have three models

- Track
- Playlist
- PlaylistTrack (or PlaylistEntry, etc, whatever you want)

The PlaylistTrack model would have a one->many relationship with both Track and Playlist, as well as an order attribute. Something like this:

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    playlist: {
      model: 'playlist'
    },
    track: {
      model: 'track'
    },
    order: 'integer'
  }
}
```

You'll also need to add the collection attribute to Playlist. You will probably want to check that the order is unique for each playlist/track combination too.

Now you can grab use the `Model.sort()` method to order the tracks correctly